# Did Russia publish any official statement regarding on the national map released by the Ministry of Natural Resources?

Tags: russian-federation, china, borders

https://www.lemonde.fr/en/international/article/2023/09/04/china-is-redefining-its-borders-with-its-neighbors-including-russia_6122600_4.html

> Was China looking to take advantage of Russia's setbacks, under
> international sanctions and embroiled in its war in Ukraine, to nibble
> away a few dozen square kilometers? On Monday, August 28, the Ministry
> of Natural Resources published the 2023 edition of the "National Map
> of China," an official document that has become the reference
> regarding "national sovereignty." In the far northeast of the country,
> China seems to have made Bolshoi Ussuriysky Island its own.
>
> Located at the confluence of the Amur and Ussuri rivers, this island
> of around 300 square kilometers has long been a subject of dispute
> between the two countries. In 1929, Russia occupied the island and
> prohibited China from navigating that part of the Amur River, which
> Beijing has always contested. In 2004, however, the two countries
> reached a compromise: The western part of the island went to China,
> which could also navigate on the Amur River, but in return, Beijing
> accepted that the eastern part would go to Russia.
>
> Although the map published on the Ministry's website is not precise
> enough to show the border clearly, the Ministry has defined its
> "scope": "The confluence of the Heilongjiang [Chinese name for the
> Amur] and Ussuri rivers is drawn to the east," it states. This
> confluence is theoretically located in Russian territory. Moreover,
> the Chinese search engine Baidu Maps does not indicate the course of
> the border in the middle of the island, but on the eastern part of the
> island, it has explicitly written "Fuyuan Delta" in Chinese, using the
> name of the Chinese district to which the western part of the island
> is administratively attached. When questioned by Le Monde, the
> Ministry of Natural Resources did not respond. Russia does not appear
> to have reacted.

Did Russia publish any official statement regarding on the national map released by the Ministry of Natural Resources? It seems strange that China is now asserting that some of its contested territory as belonging to them in this indirect way. The article was published a few months ago, and I am wondering if any statement was made since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in a press conference at the end of August 2023, Maria Zakharova, the spokeswoman for the Ministry of Foreign Affairs, [responded to a question](https://www.mid.ru/ru/foreign_policy/news/1902282/) related to the publication of the Chinese map:

> The Russian and Chinese sides share the same position that the border
> issue between our countries has been finally resolved. Its settlement
> was marked by the ratification in 2005 of the Additional Agreement on
> the Russian-Chinese state border on its eastern part, according to
> which the Bolshoy Ussuriysky Island was divided between the parties.
> The delimitation and demarcation of our common border has been
> completed along its entire length (almost 4,300 km), including in 2008
> on Bolshoy Ussuriysky Island.
>
> The resolution of the issue of the border line between Russia and
> China was the result of many years of efforts by both sides, a
> reflection of the high level of relations between the two countries,
> made an important contribution to ensuring security and stability in
> the region, and is a successful example of resolving border disputes
> for all states of the world.
>
> Russia and China have repeatedly confirmed the absence of mutual
> territorial claims; there is a corresponding provision in the Treaty
> of Good Neighbourliness, Friendship and Cooperation of July 16, 2001,
> which is the basis for bilateral relations.
>
> The parties have an extensive structure of interaction in the field of
> border cooperation; the Joint Border Commission functions effectively,
> within which all relevant issues are discussed.